# GVIFs increase after removing variables

Tags: multiple-regression, generalized-linear-model, modeling, multicollinearity, variance-inflation-factor

I have a qualitative dependent variable (Y), a dicothomic cathegorical variable (X1), a cathegorical variable (around 60 non-homogeneous groups, X2), two cathegorical variables (10-20 groups each, X3 and X4) and the date of the observation (ranging 3 years, quantitative X5). I have obtained as well the month-year (X6) of the observation. N= 300000 observations.

I want to see significant differences in Y between X2 groups over time while controlling X1 and X3 (partial correlation, but since Y is qualitative I used a glm). I have used R to create a glm (logistic regression), but I get strange GVIFs (**GVIFs are higher when they should be lower**)

Models I have tried:

1) Y ~ X6 + X1 + X2 * X5 + X3 + X4
car package gvifs:

```
    GVIF        Df      GVIF^(1/(2*Df))
```

X6                  1.379939e+03 35        1.108805

X4                  2.349995e+00 23        1.018748

X1                  1.016412e+00  1        1.008173

X3                  5.616355e+00  7        1.131182

X2                  7.019190e+209 60       56.068516

X5                  1.290364e+03  1        35.921643

X2:X5               7.006197e+209 60       56.067650

GVIFs are appalling and unaceptable, but since I'm used cathgorical variables I put more attention to corrected GVIFs (which are still very high).
I  don't need the date of the observation (X5) as a predictor and I believe it's correlated with the month (X6) so I try the following model.

2) Y ~ X6 + X1 + X2 + X2 : X5 + X3 + X4

This is the model I like the most: I can draw conclussions for changes (trend) in each group over time (X2:X5 in R glm notation) while controlling X3 and X4 and paying some attention to monthly changes (X1). I wouldn't want to have X5 instead of X1 since the monthly changes for the whole group over time don't seem to be linear.

```
 GVIF Df GVIF^(1/(2*Df))
```

X6              NaN 35             NaN

X4              NaN 23             NaN

X1              NaN  1             NaN

X3              NaN  7             NaN

X2              Inf 60             Inf

X2:X5           Inf 61             Inf

vifs obtained via rms package are also higher for the interactions than when using the previous model (up 4-5 times higher for them)

I don't understand this.
I thought by removing a variable with colinearity issues my VIFs would drop.

Comment: If X2 and X5 are highly collinear, you should only include one of the two in your model (e.g., X2). I don't understand why you would still include X2:X5 in a model which includes X2?!

Comment: 1) X2:X5 are highly colinear because I oncluded the interaction plus one or two of the variables

Comment: 2) X2:X5 (the interaction of Groups (X2) and time (X5)) is precisely the main objective of my model. I want to know which groups increase or decreease over time while controlling other factors